# How can I ssh into a windows box running cygwin/sshd and have the resulting terminal session use cygwin instead of default BASH?

Tags: python, windows, ssh, cygwin

I am trying to port my linux network automation to a set of Windows machines.  The program I have starts with a single admin console, and transmits instructions over sockets and ssh tunnels to client machines instructing them to run specific mozmill/python scripts.  I have gotten the individual client script to run on windows using cygwin, but I need to be able to call them from an ssh session, and ssh-ing in through Cygwin's sshd distribution logs me in with a basic Bash terminal instead of the Cygwin terminal.  How can I switch which terminal is used in this situation?

Comment: Cygwin isn't a shell, like bash. When you run the Cygwin *Terminal* you are probably running the *bash shell* inside of it. You probably just aren't loading the right `.bashrc` and other files.

Comment: I guess then that my issue is that I need to use the functionality of the Cygwin terminal in the ssh session, which allows the use of different syntax and commands than the basic _bash_ shell terminal.   Is it possible to ssh as if I were just logging into the simulated linux user generated by cygwin?

Comment: Got it.  The solution is simply to run the Cygwin.bat from the c:\cygwin folder, which puts you into a cygwin terminal, allowing the use of all of the needed functionality.  The same also works for the mozilla-build terminal that I neeeded.  :-D

Answer (score 1):

Got it. The solution is simply to run the Cygwin.bat from the c:\cygwin folder, which puts you into a cygwin terminal, allowing the use of all of the needed functionality. The same also works for the mozilla-build terminal that I neeeded. :-D